# Apple macbook air model 1.1 - Lubuntu 14.04 64 bit - wifi Broadcom BCM4321 doesnt work

Tags: wireless, drivers, lubuntu, broadcom, macbook

I was searching on the internet but I didnt find any answer. I have mabook air with wifi card BCM4321.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4328] (rev 05)
```

First of all, I tried this with no success:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookAir1-1/Raring#Wireless

I blacklisted all other drivers and activated wl driver. Then I was able to connect and use the wifi. But only sometimes. For now I am connected on the internet by tp-link wifi dongle.

dmesg when wifi doesnt work:

```
[    4.329798] init: plymouth-upastart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    4.504099] usb 7-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    4.681560] usb 7-1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8242
[    4.681567] usb 7-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    4.681572] usb 7-1: Product: IR Receiver
[    4.681576] usb 7-1: Manufacturer: Apple Computer, Inc.
[    4.932089] usb 7-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[    5.120575] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=0224
[    5.120582] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.120588] usb 7-2: Product: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
[    5.120592] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: Apple, Inc.
[    5.584289] usb 2-1.1: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[    5.679424] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0234
[    5.679431] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    5.679435] usb 2-1.1: Product: OM
[    5.752288] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[    5.844919] usb 2-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=8179
[    5.844923] usb 2-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.844926] usb 2-1.4: Product: 802.11n NIC
[    5.844929] usb 2-1.4: Manufacturer: Realtek
[    5.844931] usb 2-1.4: SerialNumber: 00E04C0001
[    5.921249] usb 5-2.1: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
[    6.054250] usb 5-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=8210
[    6.054256] usb 5-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    6.054261] usb 5-2.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    6.054265] usb 5-2.1: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
[    6.054269] usb 5-2.1: SerialNumber: 001F5BD72EEC
[   11.228155] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   14.895416] Adding 2075644k swap on /dev/sda3.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2075644k FS
[   14.997640] systemd-udevd[309]: starting version 204
[   15.078955] EXT4-fs (sda2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   15.083186] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[   15.088953] video: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   15.092900] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
[   15.093481] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4
[   15.116537] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[   15.177419] lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
[   15.177423] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'NULL'
[   15.182089] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   15.182096] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   15.290249] INFO @wl_cfg80211_attach : Registered CFG80211 phy
[   15.383047] lib80211_crypt: registered algorithm 'TKIP'
[   15.462473] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   15.462482] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   15.462487] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   15.462492] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   15.462494] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   15.462498] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   15.462500] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
[   15.462651] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[   15.479746] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4328 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.141 (r415941)
[   15.523651] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[   15.584363] i801_smbus 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   15.585268] i915: unknown parameter 'i915_enable_rc6' ignored
[   15.585632] ACPI Warning: 0x000000000000efa0-0x000000000000efbf SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI 1 (20131115/utaddress-251)
[   15.585639] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   15.596309] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
[   15.596339] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   15.596342] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.596356] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.596360] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.596372] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.624092] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   15.624100] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   15.624118] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   15.640396] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   15.640411] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   15.640417] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   15.650650] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 512M
[   15.650657] checking generic (80000000 640000) vs hw (80000000 10000000)
[   15.650660] fb: conflicting fb hw usage inteldrmfb vs EFI VGA - removing generic driver
[   15.650710] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
[   15.867281] type=1400 audit(1417872450.438:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=488 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.867291] type=1400 audit(1417872450.438:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=488 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.867908] type=1400 audit(1417872450.438:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=488 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.873898] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
[   15.884416] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[   15.884420] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[   15.884436] i915 0000:00:02.0: Invalid ROM contents
[   15.884441] [drm] failed to find VBIOS tables
[   15.884521] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
[   16.057582] type=1400 audit(1417872450.630:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=555 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.057593] type=1400 audit(1417872450.630:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=555 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.057599] type=1400 audit(1417872450.630:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=555 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.058213] type=1400 audit(1417872450.630:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=555 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.058221] type=1400 audit(1417872450.630:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=555 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.058536] type=1400 audit(1417872450.630:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=555 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.065067] type=1400 audit(1417872450.638:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/ntpd" pid=557 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   16.259632] init: failsafe main process (567) killed by TERM signal
[   16.330250] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   16.330254] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   16.330257] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.330260] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.330263] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.330265] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.330268] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[   16.755642] input: bcm5974 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-2/7-2:1.2/input/input5
[   16.757071] usbcore: registered new interface driver bcm5974
[   16.761210] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[   16.797769] input: Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/input/input6
[   16.798258] appleir 0003:05AC:8242.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Apple Computer, Inc. IR Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-1/input0
[   16.805783] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   16.805787] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[   16.826335] input: Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb7/7-2/7-2:1.0/input/input7
[   16.826884] apple 0003:05AC:0224.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-2/input0
[   16.832596] apple 0003:05AC:0224.0003: hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Device [Apple, Inc. Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad] on usb-0000:00:1d.2-2/input1
[   16.849758] Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[   16.867227] [drm] initialized overlay support
[   16.880358] applesmc: key=266 fan=1 temp=16 index=16 acc=1 lux=2 kbd=1
[   16.932298] input: applesmc as /devices/platform/applesmc.768/input/input8
[   16.992812] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Built-in iSight (05ac:8505)
[   16.995964] input: Built-in iSight as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-4/2-4:1.0/input/input9
[   16.996212] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   16.996215] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
[   17.017955] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[   17.245658] r8188eu: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[   17.259008] input: OM as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/input/input10
[   17.262212] hid-generic 0003:04F3:0234.0004: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [OM] on usb-0000:00:1d.7-1.1/input0
[   17.296663] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
[   17.329738] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8188eu
[   17.340237] systemd-udevd[326]: renamed network interface wlan1 to wlan2
[   17.345423] R8188EU: Firmware Version 11, SubVersion 1, Signature 0x88e1
[   17.448171] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   17.583051] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x50
[   17.586744] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
[   17.586746] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
[   17.594467] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
[   17.594544] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   17.594805] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[   17.680882] hda_codec: ALC889A: SKU not ready 0x400000f0
[   17.680985] autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x14/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
[   17.680987]    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   17.680990]    hp_outs=1 (0x15/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
[   17.680991]    mono: mono_out=0x0
[   17.680993]    inputs:
[   17.680995] realtek: No valid SSID, checking pincfg 0x400000f0 for NID 0x1d
[   17.680996] realtek: Enable default setup for auto mode as fallback
[   17.731556] input: HDA Intel Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input11
[   17.828525] MAC Address = e8:de:27:11:a9:31
[   17.840706] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan2: link is not ready
[   17.841050] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan2: link is not ready
[   17.848477] R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
[   17.849967] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan2: link is not ready
[   17.948028] [drm] GMBUS [i915 gmbus dpc] timed out, falling back to bit banging on pin 4
[   18.200028] [drm] GMBUS [i915 gmbus dpd] timed out, falling back to bit banging on pin 6
[   18.312191] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
[   19.524806] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   19.536990] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (1533) terminated with status 1
[   19.537008] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   22.099850] R8188EU: ERROR assoc success
[   22.100050] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan2: link becomes ready
[   23.016083] ACPI : EC: GPE storm detected(12 GPEs), transactions will use polling mode
[   41.043332] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[   43.115671] R8188EU: ERROR indicate disassoc
[   44.546110] R8188EU: ERROR assoc success
[   74.043282] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[   88.052042] R8188EU: ERROR linked_status_chk(wlan2) disconnect or roaming
[   90.032828] R8188EU: ERROR assoc success
[  117.049542] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  170.047559] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  233.044150] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  296.045589] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  359.044065] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  422.043768] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  485.047499] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  548.045871] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  611.043619] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  674.045744] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  737.048038] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  800.045502] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  863.047532] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  926.045665] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
[  989.049560] ERROR @wl_notify_scan_status : wlan0 Scan_results error (-22)
```

There is lsmod:

```
mac@mac-MacBookAir:~$ lsmod | grep "brcmsmac\|b43\|ssb\|bcma\|wl"
wl                   4207767  0 
lib80211               14381  2 wl,lib80211_crypt_tkip
brcmsmac              563041  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
brcmutil               15618  1 brcmsmac
bcma                   52096  1 brcmsmac
mac80211              626557  1 brcmsmac
cfg80211              484040  3 wl,brcmsmac,mac80211
```

and nm-tool:

```
mac@mac-MacBookAir:~$ nm-tools
Příkaz 'nm-tools' nebyl nalezen. Měli jste na mysli:
 Příkaz 'nm-tool' z balíku 'network-manager' (main)
nm-tools: příkaz nebyl nalezen
mac@mac-MacBookAir:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: 1E:AE:46:66:28:F0 ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:


- Device: 04:DB:56:3D:86:47 ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:


- Device: wlan2  [PobudaJ 1] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            r8188eu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        E8:DE:27:11:A9:31

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           54 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    Int:             Infra, 64:66:B3:34:BA:96, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 44 Mb/s, Strength 4 WPA2
    *PobudaJ:        Infra, 40:4A:03:80:74:67, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40
    tomas:           Infra, 94:0C:6D:FD:A3:E2, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 11 Mb/s, Strength 0 WEP
    wap_prochy:      Infra, 00:0B:6B:DA:8B:1C, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 0 WEP

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.0.0.3
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.0.0.138

    DNS:             10.0.0.138


- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:1F:5B:D7:37:FA

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points
```

Is there someone who could help me please? I spent a lot of hours looking for any solution. I must be very close because sometimes it does work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the proprietary driver wl is incorrect for your 14e4:4328 device in Ubuntu 14.04. Also, you have both that, brcmsmac *AND* the driver for your USB wireless loaded.

Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

After it finishes, detach the USB, reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

If wl continues to load after bcmwl-kernel-source is purged, then it is possible that the driver was also compiled from source. Let's blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist wl"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r wl
exit
```

Now detach the USB and tell us if the Broadcom works as expected.

Comment: Unfortunatelly there isnt. Until now there was broadcom line with status disconnected in network manager. Now I dont see anything in nm-applet.

Comment: I dont know why, but after some time in nm-applet broadcom line with disconnected status appears again.

Comment: May we see _nm-tool_ again, please?

Comment: I had to post it as an answer because of lenght.

Comment: This shows the driver _wl_ is still loaded? Did you do the purge step and reboot? You can post future diagnostics here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: I purged it but: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9398608/

Comment: Now is it still loaded? lsmod | grep wl. If not, detach the USB and see if it connects.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9399050/
It seems to be still loaded.

Comment: Please reboot and try again: lsmod | grep wl

Comment: I rebooted a couple times. Still exactly the same output. But now, even with wl, wifi works. Why sometimes it is working properly? :(

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Im sorry, I dont know which edit you mean. I did exactelly what you said - step by step. Every time with reboot and disconnected USB dongle. 
I was looking in synaptic and found that package called broadcom-sta-dkms is installed. Isnt it problem? Because this package provides the source code for the wl kernel modules.

Comment: Please remove it.

Comment: It seems to be OK! I rebooted a couple times and every time I had stable connection. wl driver isnt loaded anymore after boot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
mac@mac-MacBookAir:~$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan2  [PobudaJ 1] ---------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            r8188eu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        E8:DE:27:11:A9:31

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           54 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    wap_prochy:      Infra, 00:0B:6B:DA:8B:1C, Freq 2457 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 0 WEP
    Int:             Infra, 64:66:B3:34:BA:96, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 44 Mb/s, Strength 0 WPA2
    *PobudaJ:        Infra, 40:4A:03:80:74:67, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 18
    tomas:           Infra, 94:0C:6D:FD:A3:E2, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 11 Mb/s, Strength 0 WEP

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         10.0.0.3
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         10.0.0.138

    DNS:             10.0.0.138


- Device: 1E:AE:46:66:28:F0 ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:


- Device: 04:DB:56:3D:86:47 ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:


- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            wl
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        00:1F:5B:D7:37:FA

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points
```